# iPhone to use MFMailComposer to send email from app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my application i am able to send email using MFMailComposer.
suppose if i have gmail account in my iPhone and i am using my app to send the email , i am able to send email to others

but suppose if i have yahoo account in my iPhone and i am using my app to send email,i am not able to send email.

I really don't no what is the problem,does MFMailComposer using gmail account only or something wrong with m code.

please help me out for this.

following is my code:

```
-(void)SENDEMAIL
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
    { 
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
        NSArray* arr = [[dictUser valueForKey:@"recipients"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"mailcomporeci%@",dictUser);
        NSLog(@"arr:%@",arr);
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:arr]; 

        //[mailComposer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scheduled Email %@",arr]];
        [mailComposer setSubject:@"Scheduled Email"];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:[dictUser objectForKey:@"message"] isHTML:NO];
        mailComposer.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES]; 
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(hackMail:) userInfo:mailComposer repeats:NO];
         }
     }

-(void)hackMail:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = theTimer.userInfo;
    UIBarButtonItem *sendBtn = mailController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    id targ = sendBtn.target;
    [targ performSelector:sendBtn.action withObject:sendBtn];
}

#pragma mark Mail Compose Delegate Methods 
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {  

    switch (result) 
    { 
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled: 
        {
            break; 
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved: 
        {
            break; 
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            break; 
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed: {  

            break; 
        } 

        default:  
            break; 
    } 

    [self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error but email is not send from my yahoo account

Comment: Can you send mail from your yahoo account using the default mail app? There is no reason that MFMailVomposer would work for one account but not another, unless it is the account that is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and check out the result  :

`if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){`

`[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];`

`}`

May be your device is not configured to any account to send mail.

Comment: if i have gmail account added in my iPhone device i am able to send email from m app, but if i have yahoo account added in my device i am not able to send email from app.

Comment: May be that is because , u will have to set the mail account credentials in yahoo and gmail both.In Device go to setting and u will find Mails,Contacts,Calendar. In that Go to Add Account and configure whichever accounts u want(In your case yahoo and gmail both).